# How do you set up N2 CMS in an "enterprise" environment?

Tags: asp.net, content-management, n2

I've been playing around with the [N2 CMS](http://n2cms.com/) and I've been impressed so far. But it seems like a big jump to move from the examples to an "enterprise" grade solution.

What I really need are robust permissions and roles integrated with Active Directory. So far I've played with the membership and role providers and got things sort of rolling. But I'd really like to compare what I've done with how people are actually using the thing.

How have you customized and deployed N2 CMS in your largish organization?

**Update:**

This question has sort of become a moot point for us. We decided to use Umbraco instead since a lot of the features that we needed were included out of the box. N2 still seems like a nice system for certain things though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The N2 role & membership functionality is built to use the Membership & Role Providers from ASP.NET.  So you should just be able to drop in the active directory membership providers & start using them.  See [this post](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=63776) for a bit more information & some sample code that may help you out.

Permissions for pages & areas of the site are managed by N2 through the Security screen in the Admin section, and for ContentItems on the AvailableRoles attribute on the Page/PartDefinition attributes.  Permissions for the admin section itself are controlled in the web.config for that folder in your website.

If there's anything more specific that you need to know, you might be better off posting to the N[2 discussion list](http://n2cms.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx)

Comment: I started that thread :) I was just hoping to get some specific implementation details from people who have deployed this in a larger organization.

Comment: I had a feeling that was you :) In that case I'm not totally sure what you mean by using in an enterprise environment?

In my experience ActiveDirectory integration more or less does the trick for most people. Separate Staging/Live environments are also normally a requirement, but I haven't seen or implemented anything like this implemented in N2 bar the vanilla Import/Export functionality which doesn't really do the trick.

Comment: I do have a fairly good idea of how I can configure N2 to try to meet our needs. Whether it actually meets enough of our requirements to go forward with it isn't really my decision. 

But I'm sure that if we go through with N2 that six months later there would be a list of things that I wish I could go back in time and tell myself. That's what I was hoping to get out of this question. It would also nice to have independent confirmation that it does work in a place that has multiple departments with separate security, etc.